# How can I skip running a method with MockK or Mockito?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, mockk

When I just want to test a method is called in other method, how can I do that? I don't want the method runs after it is called.

```
fun aMethod(){
   bMethod()
}

fun bMethod(){
   // complex 
}
```

I tried this. but didn't work.

```
@Test
fun test(){
    coEvery{ mClass.bMethod() } just runs

    mClass.aMethod()

    verify { mClass.bMethod() wasNot Called }
}
```

```
@Test
fun test(){
    coEvery{ mClass.bMethod() } returns Unit

    mClass.aMethod()

    verify { mClass.bMethod() wasNot Called }
}
```

```
@Test
fun test(){
    coEvery{ mClass.bMethod() } answers { Unit }

    mClass.aMethod()

    verify { mClass.bMethod() wasNot Called }
}
```

And also I tried with `called` instead of `Called`(lowercase and uppercase C)

None of them worked. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Demigod I can mock. What do you mean? I just wanna know how to return nothing.

Comment: @Demigod I don't get it. mClass is mock class already. Could you please give more detail answer? It works when the returns value is not empty though. I don't get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems or things that are unclear in your question:

- You do not need to use `coEvery` to stub `bMethod`, because it is not a suspend function. You can see that by the fact that there is no `suspend` keyword at the start of the declaration of `bMethod`. You can and should use the regular `every` instead.
- `verify { xy wasNot Called }` is used to verify that none of the functions of a mock `xy` are called. If you want to verify that your single function `bMethod` was not called, you should instead check that it was called zero times:

```
verify(exactly = 0) { mClass.bMethod() }
```

- You are stubbing `bMethod` but not `aMethod` which lets me assume that `mClass` is not a mock but a spy, and that you intend that `aMethod`'s actual implementation is called when you call `mClass.aMethod`.
  Since `bMethod` is called inside `aMethod`, your verification that `bMethod` has not been called will always fail, because it is in fact called. The `verify` does not care whether the real implementation or a mocked implementation is called.
- So, in order to get a succeeding verification, you should either change your test to mock `aMethod` so that it really does not call `bMethod`, or you should verify that `bMethod` is called once (or at least once).

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Mockito using [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) where both methods are part of the same class:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun mockOneMethod() {
        val mock = mock<TheClass>()
        whenever(mock.aMethod()).thenCallRealMethod()
        mock.aMethod()
        verify(mock, times(1)).bMethod()
    }
}

open class TheClass {
    open fun aMethod(){
        System.out.println("a called")
        bMethod()
    }

    open fun bMethod() {
        throw NotImplementedError()
    }
}
```

Note that the methods under test must be `open` for mockito to be able to alter them.

A better option than doing "thenCallRealMethod" would possibly be to refactor the class so that `aMethod` and `bMethod` are in two different classes. Then you'd mock the entirety of the class containing `bMethod`.